# Migrate Oracle VARCHAR2(2 BYTE) into MySQL VARCHAR

Tags: mysql, oracle

I am trying to migrate one of table from Oracle to MySQL. Oracle supports Byte in Varchar2 for example i.e VARCHAR2(2 BYTE) but the same that Byte is not supporting in MySQL.

I just used VARCHAR(2) in MySQL based on this VARCHAR2(2 BYTE).

But getting data too long for column error when inserting data from oracle to MySQL.

so can anyone please suggest what is equivalent length for VARCHAR2(2 BYTE) from oracle to MySQL VARCHAR?

Comment: That is odd considering that oracle's BYTE can only be <= to its CHAR equivalent declaration. The only explanation to me is that you are using a character set in MySQL that use more bytes to store a single character than the one in Oracle. Thus what are your character sets in both databases (utf8, latin, etc...)

Comment: utf8 is using in MySQL @Thomas G

Comment: and in Oracle ?

Comment: Oracle is also same. @Thomas G